# Reverse MVC Flow in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

In codeigniter,we can easily follow the MVC flow but is it possible to fetch the data from a view to model or controller ?

Comment: yes you can fetch but it's not correct way.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world the view receives data from the controller that receives data from the model(s).

You *can* reverse/change this order. You can actually do whatever you want, but it's not recommended.

Comment: i know its not correct way to do so but that is only the way to do what i want to do with my application

Comment: if its possible then plz paste the code snippet for it

Comment: I can help you fixing your code if you need, but please don't ask me to write it A to Z for you ;)

Comment: i don't nedd A to Z code i just want some hint how to do it.That's it.